# disable editing in soapui project , sub test suites & TCs

Tags: soapui

Can i disable editing in soapui saved projects,i want to disable the edit mode in projects i send including test suites & test cases, is this possible using groovy or something?

Comment: Looks you are tagging with incorrect one, please use `soapui` tag. By the way, what do you mean by `disable editing in soapui saved projects`? If a project is not used, you can either close it or remove it from your workspace.

Comment: If you want to disable editing from an entire project you can set the project xml file as read only in the OS.

Comment: How are you "sending" these projects? This sounds more like a permissions (OS) problem, and will be very difficult to accomplish from within SoapUI.

Comment: Do you want tell the actual use case? Problem can be looked at different angle.

Comment: @Rao  iam send my project by mail and want to disable the option of modification in scripts iam adding in the project including setup script, tear down script & script assertoin, is there any way i can do that without using OS permission?

Comment: @albciff i tried your way and still can clone the project and edit it

Comment: @M.Gawad, It is not sure why would some one modifies if the project given to them is working as per the instructions? Even if they do, may be it does not matter for you if they modify it,  you are just sharing it to them to use. Just like some one posts a question and it is answered here in SO and the one who answered the question do not wish or restrict the Original Poster not to modify a shared code snippet. Makes sense?

Comment: @Rao yes i got you but the thing is that they when they modify it the project not working as expected

Comment: It is really subjective why and what they modify, one should learn aware what they are doing, even if something not working, raise to a level to handle. Use come kind of cvs repository for maintaining the projects. That helps to restore the project when some change went wrong, restart again.